# Switch from DNF to Yum (Fedora 22)

Tags: fedora, yum, package-management

I just installed Fedora 22 and - much to my surprise/anger - I found that yum has been replaced by DNF. I don't want DNF, no matter how superior it is compared to yum - how can I completely switch back to yum without downgrading my OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just keep using it. It's still installed at `/usr/bin/yum-deprecated`. If using a different name is causing you pain, you can edit the `/usr/bin/yum` script to point to this instead of to `dnf`.

While DNF is intended to be *mostly* compatible, especially for most common operations, it's not perfectly identical, so for compatibility reasons the older package will be available for the foreseeable future.

(Disclaimer: I work on Fedora, but am not directly involved in dnf or yum.)

Comment: As an aside, I'd like to understand why this change produces such a strong emotional reaction. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I know it sounds like I'm a luddite or something, but I don't enjoy having things forced down my throat. I have used yum for years, without issue, and I know yum very well. To me, it does everything I want and works fine. I don't have any need for the "features" or "improvements" provided by dnf - I have fast hardware, a very fast internet connection, etc. I would have appreciated it if I had even known that dnf was going to replace yum before I suddenly logged on to a fresh install of Fedora and found yum didn't work - not even a deprecation notice. Just a "command not found."

Answer (score 1):

`yum` has been superceded by `dnf`. It was forked off during the Fedora 18 release. You can attempt to make them live side-by-side, but you may be unsuccessful. Future releases will **not** have yum. Yum is no longer updated or worked on.

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/ReplaceYumWithDNF

Side note: F22 and F23, as of 1/30/2016, are the only releases supported and updated regularly. Downgrading to another release will be pointless.

Comment: That's sad, I suppose I'll have to switch to CentOS. Thanks for the answer!